# div inside listview in asp.net aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I wanted to show 20 items from database using a listview. but those items should be shown in two divs. 10 items in each div. The problem is, how can i build div inside listview itemtemplate for the items in aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

if the level of customization you are looking for is not easi or possible to achieve with customization of the ASP.NET listview `ItemTemplate`, you can uset the repeater object and customize its `ItemTemplate`, the repeater has been designed exactly for these cases, it supports data binding and allows you to define / customize totally the layout of items to repeat.

see here: [ASP.NET TUTORIAL. HOW TO USE REPEATER](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater)

Comment: thanks for the reply Davide Piras. actually, i am fetching 20 records at a time from database using select query inside asp:sqldatasource tag in aspx page. and then setting that sqldatasource as the datasource of the asp:listview. Now my requirement was to show those 20 items in 2 divs (10 items in each div). for example, first 10 (1 to 10) records in the first div and second 10 (11 to 20) in the second div. how can i toggle div? is this possible using repeater?